# I am STUCK! creating OOP data-structure dynamically, I think

Tags: objective-c, arrays, oop

I am close to pulling my hair out on this. I have the need to create a type of object such that when a new object is instantiated it associates itself with every other object of that class via an array property. That is `object1` gets created and has an array with no other objects. `Object 2` gets created and has an array with `object1`.  `Object 3` gets created and has an array with `object1` and `object2`.  Also `object1` and `object2` now have `object 3` in their arrays.

This has proved more difficult that I had prejudged by simply using conditional logic and `for-in` looping.

I have attempted to create an object manager class to keep a list of all objects created and use those references to loop through its owned objects and `"cross-pollinate"` them with each other.  Check for `![object1.name isEqualToStringName:thisObject.name]` in each `for-in` loop.

I imagine this may be somewhat opaque and needlessly confusing to some.  The essence of what I want to do is dynamically associate every object with every object via an array property.

The app creates `object8` and `object8` is added to the arrays of `object1`...`object7`.

This is something I am attempting to do in a larger context of an app where the objects must maintain situational awareness of each other and having an array of each other will help to facilitate that.  If there is a design pattern, methodology, principle or something I am missing here please.. please inform me.

Comment: Could you not use a `Singleton` for your `object manager`? Every time an object is created you use the singleton to add references etc to all other objects.

Comment: @al Please update your title to something more meaningful. Stackoverflow is not a forum and the rules here are very different. Also, read [ask].

Comment: @sbarow my objectManager class is a singleton.  It has an array property which contains references to all the objects I create.  When I create an object I then call `[[objectManager sharedManager] addObject:object2]`
Again, I'm still looking for this function to creating associations between all objects.  I've gotten closer since last night.